# how can you get your BASE_DIR for any script in any location in Django project?

Tags: python, django, scripting

I can import BASE_DIR in the shell as follows:

```
In [3]: from scriptcitymirror.settings import BASE_DIR

In [4]: BASE_DIR
Out[4]: '/home/cchilders/projects/django_practice/scriptcity_public'
```

but in the script that writes the app for me, I cannot import the exact same thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, subprocess, sys, re, requests, time
from scriptcitymirror.settings import BASE_DIR
```

blows up as:

```
cchilders@cody_pc:~/projects/django_practice/scriptcity_public$ robots/app_writer.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "robots/app_writer.py", line 4, in <module>
    from scriptcitymirror.settings import BASE_DIR
ImportError: No module named scriptcitymirror.settings
```

I'm stunned. Also, a way I usually do it the main directory (the urls.py file in the dir with settings.py), did not work:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()

print settings.MEDIA_URL
```

Right now my ugly work around is calling `CWD=os.getcwd()` and requiring the script to by run from the home project path. My folders look like the following pic. How can get BASE_DIR correctly anywhere within django project? (but here, I want to use them in 'robots', which is not an app. the import did not work after making a test app either). Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should not import your project's `settings` because it will be missing default settings. So, in order to get all the settings you should always import `django.conf.settings`.

Second, Django docs say `django.conf.settings` is not a module - it's an object. So you can't import individual settings.

```
# WRONG way (will not work)
from django.conf.settings import BASE_DIR


# CORRECT way
from django.conf import settings
base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR
```

See this page: [Using settings in Python code](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)